# How to make a select max statement in jooq

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

I´d like to translate the following SQL-statement to jooq syntax:

`select max(table.column) from table group by table.anothercolumn`

I've tried:

- `dsl.select(table.colum, max())`
  and
- `DSL.select(table.colum, max())`
  and
- `dsl.select(table.colum.max())`
  and
- `DSL.select(table.colum.max())`

but accordingly to Eclipse, those syntaxes are all incorrect...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not an eclipse expert but can you add your Eclipse version? And is there a plugin which supports jooq-syntax or is this embedded? In case it's a plugin please also add the version.

Comment: Can you post your entire jooq query, and also the error message you receive

Comment: What do you mean by "incorrect"? The fact that [`Field.max()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Field.html#max()) is deprecated?

Comment: simplified layout of content

Answer (score 2):

The most common mistakes when starting out with jOOQ are:

#### No code generation

Most of the examples from the jOOQ manual and from other Stack Overflow questions assume that you're using [jOOQ's code generator](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/) to reverse engineer your schema. This means that you will have generated objects like `table` (more probably `TABLE`) in generated classes.

You will need to static import all those objects, e.g. using

```java
import static com.example.generated.Tables.*;
```

Now, you can reference all your tables frmo that static import, and their columns from the tables respectively

#### No static import of `DSL.*`

Another prerequisite for most effective jOOQ usage is to static import all the methods from `DSL`:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

This will allow you to use an unqualified [`max(Field)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#max(org.jooq.Field)) aggregate function.

Both of these prerequisites are documented in the [section of the manual about how to read the manual](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/the-manual/). They are both optional, you can work with jOOQ without those static imports and always fully qualify your expressions.

#### Working example

Once you've set up code generation and static imports, the following query would work:

```java
DSLContext dsl = DSL.using(connection, dialect);

Result<?> result =
dsl.select(max(TABLE.COLUMN))
   .from(TABLE)
   .groupBy(TABLE.ANOTHERCOLUMN)
   .fetch();
```

select max(table.column) from table group by table.anothercolumn